# jQuery Variable not working with if/else

Tags: jquery

having a little issue with getting this simple if/else to work.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".sme").click(function (event) {

        var vote = $(this).attr('id');
        $('.to').html(vote);

        $(".sme").removeClass('clicked');
        $(this).addClass('clicked');
    });
});


$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".tme").click(function (event) {

        var more = $(this).attr('id');
        $('.more').html(more);


        if (typeof vote) {

            $('.error').html("ERRRROOORRRR");

        } else {

            $(".tme").removeClass('clicked');
            $(this).addClass('clicked');

        }

    });
});
```

Having an issue getting the if/else to work.

Any help would be great, Thanks!

Comment: What's your issue? What's the error?

Comment: Not getting an error, but it won't let me perform what I want in regards to the if/else area.

Comment: `vote` is a string, so it is not boolean :) you must compare it to something. It does not work like in `PHP` `$vote = "1";` `if ($vote)`...

Comment: What do you want it to do? It's not clear from your post

Comment: what is this? `typeof vote`

Comment: Sorry, should have been more clear. Looking to perform the "removeClass" snippet if the "vote" variable is not undefined.

Answer (score 2):

`vote` will always be `undefined` because it is not scoped in your click handler function for `.tme`. I think you want something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var vote = undefined;

    $(".sme").click(function (event) {

        vote = $(this).attr('id');
        $('.to').html(vote);

        $(".sme").removeClass('clicked');
        $(this).addClass('clicked');
    });

    $(".tme").click(function (event) {

        var more = $(this).attr('id');
        $('.more').html(more);


        if (vote === undefined) {

            $('.error').html("ERRRROOORRRR");

        } else {

            $(".tme").removeClass('clicked');
            $(this).addClass('clicked');

        }

    });
});
```

Comment: `typeof` returns a string, not the value `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

`vote` is a local variable for the `click` event handler. You can't call it inside another event handler, it will not exist.

Why are you using two `document ready` handlers? Just use one. I would do something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".sme").click(function (event) {

        window.vote = $(this).attr('id');
        $('.to').html(window.vote);

        $(".sme").removeClass('clicked');
        $(this).addClass('clicked');
    });

    $(".tme").click(function (event) {

        var more = $(this).attr('id');
        $('.more').html(more);

        // Two cases. If it's undefined will throw error. The same if it is a string, but its length equals to zero.
        if ( typeof window.vote == undefined || window.vote.length == 0 ) {

            $('.error').html("ERRRROOORRRR");

        } else {

            $(".tme").removeClass('clicked');
            $(this).addClass('clicked');
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: What other options does he have? He could save the value inside a DOM element, but that'll be the same as using a global variable (but more expensive in terms of access times). Anyway, as the "vote" variable is defined locally in $(".sme").click(), it will not be in the scope of $(".tme").click(). I don't see other options.

Comment: It would be better practice to create a variable scoped inside `$(document).ready(function() {`. That would be accessible to both handlers without creating a global variable.

Comment: Yeah, I see your point. Anyway, if he's using jQuery events for everything, it will act "like" a global variable. Still, thank you for your comment, you're right.